# use php session to count image views?

Tags: php, session, cookies, laravel-5

I want to count image views on my website. Until now, I set a cookie that contains the last 20 viewed images like `1254.12.963.4328.32` and so on.

This is to prevent multiple counting if somebody presses F5 / reloads the page. Also I don't want to count crawlers and spiders. (I somewhere read that bots won't set this cookie, but I don't know)

Would I count only real users, when I use the session id and save an array with the viewed image-ids in the session? I use laravel with database session driver. And how much data can be stored per session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a home-made way to do that. Of course, there are some libraries that do a better job than this. However, this is a good start. Specially, if you want to do it yourself.

```
<?php
if (!$_SESSION['counter'] || !isCrawler()) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 'whatever-counter';
}


function isCrawler() {
    $crawlers = array('googlebot'); //add more crawlers agents
    foreach ($crawlers as $crawler) {
        if (strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), strtolower($crawler))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: so it is not sufficient to count if session-cookie is set ? i know nothing about crawlers / spiders

Comment: `Also I don't want to count crawlers and spiders.` The method isCrawler() will taking care. And not, it is not sufficient to count if sessions set, since they might not store the session or they maight clear session per request. Who knows what they do. Specially "bad-Boys" Bots

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to determ by browser.

See in to this project which provide browser list and documentation how to catch it.

[BrowsCap](http://browscap.org/)

Answer (score 1):

**Would I count only real users, when I use the session id and save an array with the viewed image-ids in the session?**
No. I guess the answer is no to question if you would count real users because you would have to require some action to verify that it is a real user. That's why - for example captchas are used when submtting forms.

However, you could narrow it down though so you could check `"who's"` browsing your page. You've got a great answer from **Lea Tano** which I beiieve would give you a hint where to start.

**And how much data can be stored per session?**
Sessions are (by default) stored to the server, so the actual limits is determined by PHP's [memory_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) and diskspace (on the server).